# Kendo UI events not fired for kendo-grid-react-wrapper

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

None of the following [filterMenuInit](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/filtermenuinit), [columnmenuinit](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/columnmenuinit) events are not fired.
I found a question on the forum https://www.telerik.com/forums/filtermenuinit-event-not-fired and the recommendation is to use [columnmenuinit](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/columnmenuinit) as I also have columnMenu: true configured. But [columnmenuinit](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/columnmenuinit) is not fired as well.
I use '@progress/kendo-grid-react-wrapper' so that could be the case or some configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the version as some of the events were added later.

In [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uhduni?file=app/main.js) the event is fired

```
            <Grid dataSource={this.dataSource}
            filterable={true}
            columnMenu={true}
            columnMenuInit={(e)=> alert("column menu init")}
```